# How to style QTabBar close button

Tags: qt

Is there a way to assign CSS style for the QTabBar close button?
Normally [QTabBar](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) can be styled, but I can't find its how button can be referenced from CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like there is not currently a way to style the close button via Qt style sheets.  Not only is it not documented, there doesn't seem to be a style for it in src/gui/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp.

You can set the button using `QTabBar::setTabButton()` method.

You may want to submit it as a feature request on the [Qt Bug Tracker](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Since Qt 4.6, the close buttons can be styled us QStyleSheets:

 `QTabBar::close-button {
     image: url(close.png)
     subcontrol-position: left;
 }
 QTabBar::close-button:hover {
     image: url(close-hover.png)
 }`

Answer (score 15):

As noted in a comment above, since Qt 4.6 you can use following style:

```
 QTabBar::close-button {
     image: url(close.png);
     subcontrol-position: left;
 }
```