# PyQt5: Can't see close buttons in QTabBar

Tags: python, macos, button, pyqt5, qtabbar

I can't see the close button on individual tabs when using PyQt5. I can close the individual tabs when I click where I know the close button should be, but can't see the button outright:

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QVBoxLayout,
                            QTabBar, QFrame)

class App(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Web Browser")
        self.setBaseSize(683, 384)
        self.CreateApp()

    def CreateApp(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab_Bar = QTabBar(movable=True, tabsClosable=True)
        self.tab_Bar.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.CloseTab)

        self.tab_Bar.addTab("Tab 1")
        self.tab_Bar.addTab("Tab 2")

        self.tab_Bar.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tab_Bar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def CloseTab(self, i):
        self.tab_Bar.removeTab(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using Python version 3.6.2 and PyQt5 version 5.9

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on linux. What platform are you on, and what widget style are you using?

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.11.6, I'm using the QTabBar widget (second line of CreateApp function) if that is what your asking. If it's something else, how can I find out?

Comment: As an experiment, try putting the line `QApplication.setStyle('Fusion')` before `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Comment: That was cool, it put ninja-esque close buttons on the right side of each tab, and without the setStyle, I put 'print(app.style())' after 'window=App()' which returned '<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle object at 0x109dd3168>'

Comment: What is the output of `print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())`? Try setting each of the styles to see if it makes any difference. You could also try setting your own icon using the stylesheet shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032326/984421). This should at least determine whether the tabs can show icons on your system.

Comment: The print command outputted a 3-element list: `['Windows', 'Fusion', 'Macintosh']` and after trying all three, `Windows` and `Fusion` both produce icons, however `Macintosh` does not. BUT setting up my own icon using a stylesheet worked

Comment: Huh. Looks like a bug in the Mac style, then. And here it is: [QTBUG-61092](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61092). Seems to have been fixed in Qt-5.9.2.