# PyQt5 - Missing close button icon in QTabBar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtabbar

I'm trying to set my tabs "Closable", however I can't see the close button icon on individual tabs when using PyQt5 and "Fusion" style:

[image]

When I set "Windows" style I can see:

[image]

I already tried to use styleSheet qtabbar button but it didn't work:

```
    QTabBar::close-button {
     image: url(close.png);
     subcontrol-position: left;
 }
```

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QVBoxLayout,
                            QTabBar, QFrame)

class App(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Web Browser")
        self.setBaseSize(683, 384)
        self.CreateApp()

    def CreateApp(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab_Bar = QTabBar(movable=True, tabsClosable=True)
        self.tab_Bar.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.CloseTab)

        self.tab_Bar.addTab("Tab 1")
        self.tab_Bar.addTab("Tab 2")

        self.tab_Bar.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tab_Bar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def CloseTab(self, i):
        self.tab_Bar.removeTab(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    QApplication.setStyle('Fusion')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using Python version 3.6.2 and PyQt5 version 5.10.

What could be the root cause of this problem? Maybe my system is lacking some icons in Fusion style?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104347/pyqt5-cant-see-close-buttons-in-qtabbar). Though it does not have an official answer, there are some suggestions in comments. Do check them. Since it is working for "Windows" and not for "Fusion", can be a bug in QT5.

Comment: Yes, I already read that topic but that refers to an issue caused by QT 5.9.0 and it was fixed in 5.9.2.
In my case I'm using QT 5.6.0. I was searching in https://bugreports.qt.io/ and it seems that in this version works fine.